# Wait for query table to refresh

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

A listobject (LO1) is connected to a PowerQuery Querytable (QT1).

I want to

- refresh QT1
- wait until the refresh is done
- protect the worksheet that contains LO1, in order to ensure that the table contents cannot be changed

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
sub qtrefresh()

Set LO1 = mySheet.ListObjects("myListobject")
Set QT1= LO1.QueryTable
QT1.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Do While QT1.Refreshing
DoEvents
Loop 

mySheet.Protect 

end sub
```

This does not work. I can see the spinning icon in the workbook queries panel. The .refreshing property however seems to stay in status "false". The code continues and the sheet is protected immediately. Because of that the query refresh finishes with the warning message "Download did not complete".

I disabled the "Enable background refresh" parameter in the connection setting.

I tried to disable the parameter progammatically:

```
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - xyz").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
```

I tried this:

```
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

And this:

```
Application.Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

And this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Calculate
Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Not sure if this is relevant:

QT1 is not an external connection. Instead it just reads from an existing table in the same workbook.

The application runs on Excel 2016.

Comment: What about just using `DoEvents` without the Do While? That's how I let my queries refresh before continuing a macro.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but could it be that the refresh has not yet started when your `Do While QT1.Refreshing` line first runs and so the loop is exited immediately? Try putting another `DoEvents` between `QT1.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` and `Do While QT1.Refreshing` or move the loop into a separate procedure that is called using `Application.OnTime` a second or so later?

Comment: I noticed that once you disable the "Enable background refresh" parameter in the connection setting, the .refreshing property no longer indicates as "true". Just using DoEvents however seems to work as the execution of the subsequent code is delayed. The only thing that doesn't properly work is the sheet protection (causes warning message "Download did not complete").

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    Sub qtrefresh()
    
    Set LO1 = mySheet.ListObjects("myListobject")
    Set QT1 = LO1.QueryTable
    QT1.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    
    'Do While QT1.Refreshing
    DoEvents
    'Loop
    
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "protect_sheet"
    
    End Sub

    Sub protect_sheet()
    
    mySheet.Protect
    
    End Sub
```

KR
Gerrit